# Unexpected file found in package directory

Tags: salesforcedx

I've worked on developing ligthing component using sfdx and till some point everything worked fine. Today I got latest changes from my git repo and tried to make `sfdx force:source:push` but it failed with a message `Unexpected file found in package directory: path_to_my_source\force-app\main\default\classes\MyCustomApex.cls`. I spent some time investigating this but at some point of time I decided to start from the scratch but still got the same exception. Here is what I did:

1. Cloned my repository to the new folder
2. Authorzied in DevHub trial using `sfdx force:auth:web:login -a DevHub -d -s`
3. Created new scratch org using `sfdx force:org:create -a MyNewOrg -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json`
4. Installed Lightning Test Service using `sfdx force:lightning:test:install`

Now I try to push my cloned sources into the scratch org using `sfdx force:source:push` but keep getting this error. I tried to checkout the version that for sure had only my code and worked for me but the error remained. Am I doing something wrong? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Could another developer have checked in that file without its meta-xml file?

Comment: No, it seems that MyCustomApexcls-meta.xml is there. Also there were no changes to this file, and furthermore, other devs in my team don't have this kind of problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know the root cause, but reinstallation of SFDX CLI helped (no changes of the source code)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85248)

Comment: You want me to request clarification from myself?

Comment: Does not work for me. I have slight different error: ERROR:  Unexpected file found in package directory: /**/src/dashboards/Power_Router_Dashboards-meta.xml.